# Why is Youtube Fullscreen toggle(f) not working in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, youtube

The same toggle works fine in other browsers like edge and chrome. Also the other toggles are working fine, i.e. j, k, l etc, for pausing and forwarding.

Comment: Are you experiencing this issue with [an embed video](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780)? If you could [share us the webpage where you are experiencing this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would help us to help you.

Comment: It is occuring with any youtube video I play.

Comment: Could you precise your OS and Firefox versions?

Comment: OS: Windows 11 22H2
Firefox 105.0.3 (64-bit)